# Is it possible to encrypt a Web.Config connection string on an Azure web site hosted on the Free web site model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

There's plenty of articles that show how to encrypt a Web.Config connection string but they all require the admin to upload a certificate.

I can't see any way of uploading a cert to a site hosted in the 'Free' mode.

Answer (score 1):

By default SQL DB Connection string is encrypted before storing in DB so if that your objective it is already done. If you are looking for encrypting App Settings (which you can created directly at Portal), those are still not encrypted however they are part of Azure WebSites team next release so will be available soon possibly in next update.